# Whether $(A \setminus B= \{ 1 \}) \rightarrow (1 \in A \lor 1 \notin B)$ is a tautology.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question: whether $(A \setminus B= \{ 1 \}) \rightarrow (1 \in A \lor 1 \notin B)$ is a tautology.

I am not sure if the statement above is always true (tautology) since by the definition of difference, if an element $a \in A \setminus B$, we can infer that $(a \in A \land a \notin B)$, which is different from the statement. However, I can't find a situation that makes the question's statement to be false, which causes me trouble determining whether it is a tautology.

Can anyone help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: Note that we can infer $a \in A \lor a \notin B$ from $a \in A \land a \notin B$ always.

Answer (score 2):

Aloha, welcome to Math SE :) I believe the statement is a tautology. Here is my proof.

Like your comment suggests, we have that

$a \in A \setminus B \iff a \in A \land a \notin B$

We also have $A \setminus B = \{ 1 \}$, there is only one element so $a$ is that element. Thus, $a \in A \setminus B \iff a = 1$. So whenever we see an $a$ we may substitute it into our expression.

$1 \in A \setminus B \iff 1 \in A \land 1 \notin B$

Now we definitely know that

$1 \in A \setminus B \implies 1 \in A$ by conjunction elimination.

Then we have

$1 \in A \setminus B \implies 1 \in A \lor 1 \notin B$ by disjunction introduction.

We may put everything together:

\begin{align}
(A \setminus B = \{ 1 \})
&\iff (a \in A \setminus B \iff a = 1) \\
&\implies 1 \in A \setminus B \iff 1 \in A \land 1 \notin B \\
&\implies 1 \in A \\
&\implies 1 \in A \lor 1 \notin B \\
\end{align}

There are a lot of crazy arrows, but the main thing is that we can always go from left to right. So we may deduce, $(A \setminus B = \{ 1 \}) \implies (1 \in A \lor 1 \notin B)$

Does this answer the question? Let me know what else I may add.

Comment: I don't see that you have proven that the given statement is a *tautology* (it isn't; it's merely mathematically true).